# How I can change the rate of audio file playing?

Tags: java, audio-streaming, jmf

I have the following main class in java JMF ,I need to increase the playing of the audio file test.wav im trying the setRate instuction but it doesn't work:

Here is the main class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.media.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;

public class HelloJMF 
{

    static JFrame frame = new JFrame(" Hello JMF Player");

    static Player helloJMFPlayer = null;

    public static void main( String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            URL url=new URL("file:///d:\\testJMF.wav");
            helloJMFPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(url);
        } 
        catch( Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println(" Unable to create the audioPlayer :" + e );
        }
        Component control = helloJMFPlayer.getControlPanelComponent();
        frame.getContentPane().add( control, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() 
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) 
            {
                helloJMFPlayer.stop();
                helloJMFPlayer.close();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.setSize( new Dimension(400,100) );
        frame.setVisible(true);
        helloJMFPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

I need to change the rate of playing, I tried :

```
helloJMFPlayer.setRate(3);
```

but it doesn't work, I need your help please.

Comment: Which value does helloJMFPlayer.setRate(3) return ?

Answer (score 2):

In theory, a `Player` objects rate could be set to any real number, with negative
rates interpreted as playing the media in reverse. However, some
media formats have dependencies between frames that make it impossible
or impractical to play them in reverse or at non-standard rates.
To set the rate, you call `setRate` and pass in the temporal scale factor as a
ßoat value. When `setRate` is called, the method returns the rate that is
actually set, even if it has not changed. `Players` are only guaranteed to
support a rate of 1.0.

So the `WAV` format have this dependency so you cant change the rate .
have fun ^_^

please dont forget to subscribe my answer ^_^